# How to add active event listener for onWheel event in CxJS?

Tags: javascript, cxjs

I have a div, on which I want to add an onWheel event listener and prevent the default behavior.

```js
onWheelAction(e, {store}) {
   e.prevetDefault();
   ...
}
```

```html
<div onWheel="onWheelAction">
   ...
</div>
```

This throws an error that `preventDefault` cannot be done in the passive event listener. How can I convert it to an active listener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onWheel` is a passive event listener from React ([here](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/19654)) and Cx does not override it.

To make this work, instead of `onWheel`, you can use `onRef` attribute, which accepts a callback, with the first parameter being the element. Then, you can add an active listener on that element with the `addEventListenerWithOptions` method which is available in Cx, and prevent default behavior.

```js
import { addEventListenerWithOptions } from 'cx/util';

let unsubscribeScroll: () => void;

addElementListener(el: Element) {
    if (unsubscribeScroll) unsubscribeScroll();
    if (!el) return;
    unsubscribeScroll = addEventListenerWithOptions(
    el,
    'wheel',
    (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
             ...
       },
     { passive: false }
    );
}
```

```html
<div onRef='addElementListener'>
  ...
</div>
```